Implementing multitenanted authn and authz in .NET Core
I have a scenario where I need to authorize my API for each of my tenants with a different IDP.
So api/v1/tenants/123/woop would be authorized by the IDP belonging to 123.
The bearer token passed to this API will be issued by the tenant specific IDP.
My approach I'm taking is to implement a custom ISecurityTokenValidator. This would configure the TokenValidationParameters options each time and pass to this to the JwtSecurityTokenHandler
i.e.
public class TenantSpecificTokenValidator: ISecurityTokenValidator
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public TenantSpecificTokenValidator(IConfiguration configuration, HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public bool CanReadToken(string securityToken) => true;

    public ClaimsPrincipal  ValidateToken(string securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // lovely bespoke configuration of validationParameters

        // Use built-in JwtSecurityTokenHandler to validate the token
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        return handler.ValidateToken(securityToken, validationParameters, out _);
    }

    public bool CanValidateToken => true;

    public int MaximumTokenSizeInBytes { get; set; }
}

So I wire this up in my program.cs i.e.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
    options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new TenantSpecificTokenValidator());
   options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
       ValidateSignatureLast = true, 
       ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false
    };
});

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

When I hit an API endpoint with a valid bearer token etc I immediately get a 401 with an error message in the response

Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"

and my custom token validator isn't even called. If I put a break point on the line
options.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear(); 

it does get hit.
I was expecting my code to be responsible for checking the signature key!
If I explicitly add a signature key
IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcdefghi12345"))) 

to my code this still results in a 401 and my code is not executing!
Why isn't my custom validator being called?
